# Multiple references to @OneToMany bag relationships using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, persistence

I have following (1:n) relationship: SchoolClass -> Students. `SchoolClass` can have multiple students, and `Student` can be assigned to only one `SchoolClass`. In Hibernate (`SchoolClass` class), I have following:

```
    private transient List students;

    /**
     * @return Returns students.
     * @hibernate.bag lazy="true" cascade="all" where="(graduated_with_honors=0)" 
     * @hibernate.collection-key column="class_id"
     * @hibernate.collection-one-to-many class="my.project.namespace.Student"
     */
    public List getStudents() {
        if (students == null) {
            students = new Vector();
        }
        return students;
    }
```

Now, I want to create another method, that lists all the Students of the SchoolClass (also the ones, that graduated with honours, **so `graduated_with_honors` can be either 0 or 1**). I have tried following:

```
    private transient List students, allStudents;

    /**
     * @return Returns students.
     * @hibernate.bag lazy="true" cascade="all" where="(graduated_with_honors=0)" 
     * @hibernate.collection-key column="class_id"
     * @hibernate.collection-one-to-many class="my.project.namespace.Student"
     */
    public List getStudents() {
        if (students == null) {
            students = new Vector();
        }
        return students;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns students.
     * @hibernate.bag lazy="true" cascade="all" 
     * @hibernate.collection-key column="class_id"
     * @hibernate.collection-one-to-many class="my.project.namespace.Student"
     */
    public List getAllStudents() {
        if (allStudents == null) {
            allStudents = new Vector();
        }
        return allStudents;
    }
```

But this is not good approach, because now we have **two collections that are modifying one table** (it would throw `hibernate found shared references to a collection` exception) when used.

Does anybody know how to do this? Or, is there a way, **how to insert a parameter into `@hibernate.bag where` clause**, so we would change `where` clause according to the situation?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
private transient List students;
```

- this have to stay the same, I have to keep it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things that are wrong in your mapping:

1. Collections should always be non-nullable:

   ```
   private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
2. Why do you use a `Vector` instead of a `List`? The `Vector` is synchronized, while the `ArrayList` is not. Do you really want to use an entity concurrently?
3. You can't use the term `class` which is reserved in java, so maybe it's better to rename it to `Course`.
4. The `graduated_with_honors` relation can be best represented with a boolean in the `Student` class.

   ```
   private boolean graduatedWithHonor;
   ```

Then, you can simply query all the `Student(s)` which have graduated with honor:

```
Course course = ...;

List<Student> honourableStudents = entityManager.createQuery(
        "select s " +
        "from Student s " +
        "where s.graduatedWithHonor = true " +
        "and s.course = :course", Student.class)
.setParameter("course", course)
.getResultList();
```

Comment: I have renamed Class to SchoolClass (This was just a simplified example, so I used Class unwisely, sorry for that). And I have to use Vector, this part of code I cannot change.

Comment: I see. Well, you can use the boolean flag nevertheless.